# Snakemake and STAR

Tags: snakemake

I'm getting started with Snakemake but I feel I am missing some key concepts...

What I have is directory of fastq files and I want to run STAR on all read pairs.

I wrote the following snakefile:

```
import os
from glob import glob

experiment_name = 'swo-406'
scratch_data_base_dir="/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch"
scratch_data_dir = os.path.join(scratch_data_base_dir, experiment_name)

seqrun = '180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3'
fastq_dir = os.path.join(scratch_data_dir, 'fastq', seqrun)
preprocessing_dir = os.path.join(scratch_data_dir, 'preprocessing', seqrun)
if not os.path.isdir(preprocessing_dir):
    os.makedirs(preprocessing_dir)

ref_base_dir = '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/data/references/Reference_Genomes/GRCh38.87'
ref_genome = os.path.join(ref_base_dir, 'Homo_sapiens.GRCh38.dna.primary_assembly.fa')
star_ref_dir = '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-390/STAR_references/human'

log = os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, 'log.txt')

SAMPLES = set([os.path.basename(fastq_file.replace('_R1_001.fastq.gz', '').replace('_R2_001.fastq.gz', ''))
        for fastq_file in glob(os.path.join(fastq_dir, '*_R*_001.fastq.gz'))
        if not 'Undetermined' in fastq_file])

print(expand(os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz'), sample=SAMPLES))

# Rule all is a pseudo-rule that tells snakemake what final files to generate.
rule all:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, '{sample}.Aligned.out.bam'), sample=SAMPLES)

rule star_map:
    input:
        read1 = expand(os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz'), sample=SAMPLES),
        read2 = expand(os.path.join(fastq_dir, '{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz'), sample=SAMPLES)
    output:
        os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, '{sample}.Aligned.out.bam')
    log:
        log
    shell:
        """
        STAR \
        --runThreadN 8 \
        --genomeDir {star_ref_dir} \
        --readFilesIn {input.read1} {input.read2} \
        --outSAMtype BAM Unsorted \
        --outFileNamePrefix {output} \
        --outStd Log \
        {log}
        """
```

This outputs:

```
['/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S4_S14_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S06_S6_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S5_S15_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S03_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S10_S10_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S2_S12_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S05_S5_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S02_S2_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S3_S13_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S04_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S07_S7_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S08_S8_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S6_S16_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S09_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S1_S11_R1_001.fastq.gz', '/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S01_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz']
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:

THERE IS TEXT HERE BUT IT REFUSED TO BE PASTED??

rule star_map:
    input: /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S4_S14_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S06_S6_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S5_S15_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S03_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S10_S10_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S2_S12_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S05_S5_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S02_S2_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S3_S13_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S04_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S07_S7_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S08_S8_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S6_S16_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S09_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S1_S11_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S01_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S4_S14_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S06_S6_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S5_S15_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S03_S3_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S10_S10_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S2_S12_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S05_S5_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S02_S2_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S3_S13_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S04_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S07_S7_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S08_S8_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S6_S16_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S09_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S1_S11_R2_001.fastq.gz, /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S01_S1_R2_001.fastq.gz
    output: /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/preprocessing/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S06_S6.Aligned.out.bam
    log: /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/preprocessing/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/log.txt
    jobid: 7
    wildcards: sample=0054_P2017SEQE83S06_S6

Error in job star_map while creating output file /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/preprocessing/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S06_S6.Aligned.out.bam.
RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 40 of /home/nlv24077/experiments/experiments/swo-406/scripts/Snakefile.snakefile:
Command '
        STAR         --runThreadN 8         --genomeDir /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-390/STAR_references/human         --readFilesIn /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S4_S14_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S06_S6_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S5_S15_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S03_S3_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S10_S10_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S2_S12_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S05_S5_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S02_S2_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S3_S13_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S04_S4_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S07_S7_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S08_S8_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S6_S16_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S09_S9_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S1_S11_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S01_S1_R1_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S4_S14_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S06_S6_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S5_S15_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S03_S3_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S10_S10_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S2_S12_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S05_S5_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S02_S2_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S3_S13_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S04_S4_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S07_S7_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S08_S8_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S6_S16_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S09_S9_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2018SEQE15S1_S11_R2_001.fastq.gz /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/fastq/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S01_S1_R2_001.fastq.gz         --outSAMtype BAM Unsorted         --outFileNamePrefix /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/preprocessing/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/0054_P2017SEQE83S06_S6.Aligned.out.bam         --outStd Log         /rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/preprocessing/180413_NB501997_0054_AHTFJ3BGX3/log.txt
        ' died with <Signals.SIGSEGV: 11>.
  File "/home/nlv24077/experiments/experiments/swo-406/scripts/Snakefile.snakefile", line 40, in __rule_star_map
  File "/rst1/2017-0205_illuminaseq/scratch/swo-406/snakemake/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 56, in run
Will exit after finishing currently running jobs.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

As you can see, I get all fastq files as input for STAR, it does not cycle through the samples as I would expect. How would I do that?

Highest regards,

Freek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define what `{sample}` wildcard is in `rule all`. In example below, snakemake will run for samples A and B.

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand(os.path.join(preprocessing_dir, '{sample}.Aligned.out.bam'), sample=['A', 'B'])
```

[Here](https://molb7621.github.io/workshop/Classes/snakemake-tutorial.html) is a tutorial that I found useful in the past.

Comment: Ah, thanx, this helps a lot! Nice tutorial also. I have indeed now added a list of SAMPLES and it sort of works now (will post everything I did when it really works). But now, it uses all samples as input for STAR, see my revised question.

Comment: Ok, I should only expand the rule all input, not the rest! Is still crashes now but it is STAR related I think, will update later.

Comment: Ok, I have it running thanks to your help, what should I do? Update the question with the working Snakemake file?

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Accept it as answer (tick mark) and that should do.